# Ida Pro Radare2 LD_PRELOAD

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm doing an exploit type challenge. The challenge's binary to exploit uses a modified version of `libc.so`.

So before running linux server or radare2 / ida, the export environment variable `LD_PRELOAD=/path2/libc_modified.so` and then I put a breakpoint at the first assembly statement of the `main`. With `ida` I cannot launch binary however I can attach to process, but the breakpoints inserted after a read are bypassed so ida cannot stop and I can't debug binary.

With `radare2` I can launch binary but breakpoint inserted at first instruction of main are bypassed.

I can debug executables that doesn't use libraries to be loaded with the `LD_PRELOAD` and my breakpoints are catched.

Does anyone know the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Don't add `LD_PRELOAD` to the start command of your IDA/r2, as your modified libc can be overmodified and will break IDA/r2. Try to change environment variables from IDA or r2 to change them only for target application. Also check for static constructors (init sections) which runs before `main()`, and the output of `ltrace -S ./target_app` can be useful too.

Comment: I suggest you ask on the StackExchange [reverse engineering site](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)